# How can I write float image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, c, opencv

Someone gave me this function:

```
Mat tan_triggs_preprocessing(InputArray src, float alpha = 1, float gamma = 10.0,
                 float tau = 1000.0, int sigma1 = 2) {
  Mat X = src.getMat();
  Mat I, tmp, tmp2;
  double meanI;

  X.convertTo(X, CV_32FC1);
  pow(X, gamma, I);

  meanI = 0.0;
  pow(abs(I), alpha, tmp);
  meanI = mean(tmp).val[0];
  I = I / pow(meanI, 1.0/alpha);

  meanI = 0.0;
  pow(min(abs(I), tau), alpha, tmp2);
  meanI = mean(tmp2).val[0];
  I = I / pow(meanI, 1.0/alpha);

  for(int r = 0; r < I.rows; r++) {
    for(int c = 0; c < I.cols; c++) {
      I.at<float>(r,c) = tanh(I.at<float>(r,c) / tau);
    }
  }
  I = tau * I;

  return I;
}
```

The function takes an input as a gray scale image or CV_8UC1 type, and it outputs a matrix of CV_32FC1 type. All I know is the function makes the input image lighter, increases its contrast. When I show the image using `imshow` function, I can see the output of `tan_triggs_preprocessing` very clearly, and actually the output lighter, more contrast compares to the source image. But the problem is when I save it as image format (JPG for example) using `imwrite` function, it's totally black. I can't see anything.
I checked the value of elements in the output, and I saw that their values are between [0.06.., 2.3...]. Here are my questions, hopefully you can help me, thank you so much.

1. Can I write an CV_32FC1 as image file format?
2. Why is the file written by `imwrite` above totally black?
3. I also looked for min and max value in the output, so I can normalize it in to 256 bins for CV_8UC1, but it doesn't work, even when I use `imshow` or `imwrite`.
4. How can I convert it to CV_8UC1 or write it as image file format? I used `convertTo` but it doesn't work as well.

Thank a lot.

Comment: You can save the image as an HDR image, .hdr files are floating point. To do this you'll need to use OpenCV 3.0, which is currently in beta.

Comment: Hi maggick. Thank you so much for your attention. I will think about it.

Answer (score 2):

imwrite/imread can only handle 8/16/24/32bit integral data, not floats (if you don't count Ilm/exr)

you probably want :

```
Mat gray_in = ...
Mat gray_out;
cv::normalize( tan_triggs_preprocessing(gray_in), gray_out, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);
```

(admittedly hard to spot, but it's even in the small print of bytefish's code ;)

also, please look at alternatives to that, like  [equalizehist](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html#equalizehist) and [CLAHE](http://answers.opencv.org/question/12024/use-of-clahe/)

Comment: Hi berak. Thank you so much but the `gray_out` is still too dark. It is not as bright and sharp as `tan_triggs_preprocessing(gray_in)`

Comment: Do you have any idea to deal with it? Thanks.

Comment: a couple, but it takes *work* and it's late here. different flags apart from NORM_MINMAX, or straight tantriggs_output.convertTo(gray_out, CV_8U,255);

Comment: oh, and don't forget to play with alpha,gamma,tau, etc

Comment: honestly, it never worked reallly [nice](https://github.com/berak/uniform-lbp/blob/master/readme.md) for me this way, but i'll give it another try tomorrow. maybe the normalizing on top of it is plain wrong

Comment: sorry for annoying you again. The result with `converTo(gray_out, CV_8U, 255)` is better, but when I write it using imwrite, the image file is very different from the output. Do you know why? I think they must be the same, but it turns out they are not.

Comment: you're not annoying, the opposite. i'm just too lazy to try anything myself this evening. so imshow() differs from the file on disk ? hmm. i'll put it on the list ;)

Comment: imshow does some funny tricks behind the scene, so when in doubt, trust the file on disk.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, they are different. I don't know what happening here. Can show image with `imshow` but can't write with `imwrite`. Also, normalize it or multiply each its value to scale it break the image.

Comment: If imshow does some tricks, then perhaps the result using `convertTo` is not good as I see it in `imshow` window. :(

Comment: what are you finally trying to use the tan-triggs for ? detection ? recognition ? only applying it to the real thing will tell.

Comment: I had some ideas to equalize the card brightness, but they didn't work as I expected. So I use his `tan_triggs_preprocessing` which I don't know what happened in that function.

Comment: I also tried histogram equalization, but it made the cards look... ugly. :(

Comment: k,k. still, leave no stone unturned ;)